# mesh not connected properly to the bones

Tags: rigging, bones, vertices, extrude

I have an issue where my head aren't connected with the bones when I'm moving the root bone. but when I rotate it, the head does connect with the bones direction. How can I solve this problem ? [image][image]

Comment: hello please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @moonboots i can't seem to able to upload it there

Comment: or use another platform and share the link   ;)

Comment: you've given a Copy Rotation constraint to your head, it will make the head rotate on the same axis as the bone, but head and bone axis are not aligned, why don't you simply parent the head to the bone?

Comment: @moonboots i have tried your suggestion. But I still cant find the right solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

you've given a *Copy Rotation* constraint to your head, it will make the head rotate on the same axis as the bone, but head and bone axis are not aligned. Also, it won't make the head follow the armature. What you can do is remove these constraints, select the head for example, shift select the armature, switch it to *Pose* mode, select the head bone and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> *(Set Parent to) > Bone*.

Comment: THANK YOU ! PROBLEM SOLVED. OWE YOU A LOT. Hopefully i can submit my assignment soon :)